# iPhone app: tap this button to update to the latest version

Tags: iphone, app-store

I basically need a url to open that will end up at the updates tab of the AppStore app.  Preferably at the update screen for my app.  Is such a thing possible?

I know you can open the app itself, or even the reviews page for the app.  But when prompting users to upgrade, the "buy/free" button is actually grayed out and says "installed".  Which is pretty unintuitive.  We could just have text that instructs the user what to do, but it would be far better we could go directly the update page for our app.  We can remotely update content in our old app, so it would be easy to have button or link that takes them to the update tab, assuming I knew what the magic url was.

Comment: That's the type of thing you should make sure to enter into Apple's bug reporter system as an enhancement request, that they make such a URL available in some future rev of iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such URL. About all you can do is tell the user to check the App Store for an update and block them from progressing further into your app until they've installed the new version.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has found a URI that will link to your app's update page:

[how do you link directly to app store app update page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904207/how-do-you-link-directly-to-app-store-app-update-page)

You'll find the answer in the question. Frankly, I'd prefer an update URI as well.