# how do you link directly to app store app update page?

Tags: iphone, ios, hyperlink

I'm finishing up an iPhone app. I'm using an external server to inform users of when an update is available for my app and allowing them to click from within the app to go straight to the update on the app store. Problem is, I can't seem to figure out the link format to go directly to the update. I've found an old method of using **viewsoftwareUpdate** (mentioned in another post here) but it's all related to outdated phobos links and I can't seem to get it working for me. I'm currently using the simple format to link directly to the app: itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/"appname", and I assume there is a way to alter this format to get to the app update instead of the main app page?

This seems like a pretty basic functionality so I'm surprised I can't find anything on it.

Also, does anybody know how to link directly to the users own update tab in the app store? Not specific to one app, but the update tab that shows all the updates they have available for download.

Comment: Could not get this link to work.

Comment: Me neither. Kept saying 'Could not connect to iTunes store'.

Comment: Are you using it on an actual device for an app that you have an update waiting for? Otherwise, it's not going to work. I tried it on 3 different live apps that I personally had updates waiting for (just put their app id in) and it went straight to the update page for every single one.

Comment: Just as an FYI, if it's solved, it's generally best to post your own Answer and then accept it as correct. That way, future users know not to come here to answer the question, and can also find the proper answer more easily. (I know this is a bit late, just saw the link on Twitter)

Comment: Gabe: I edited/moved your answer out of the Question and into an Answer (marked community wiki).  If you can accept that answer then people can see that this is answered.  I was looking for this answer and finally found it in the question.

Answer (score 8):

Turns out the phobos links do still work and you can link directly to the update page using this URL format:

itms-apps://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftwareUpdate?id=[APPID]&mt=8

Of course replacing the [APPID] with your own app id, not including the brackets. This will link directly to the latest update for the app, instead of the main app page.

[Note: the solution was posted in with the question, I just moved it here --progrmr]

Comment: Getting "itunes could not process the request" error with a genuinely pending update app. (iOS 5 beta 5).

Comment: I just tried it out with on of my apps that I haven't updated yet and it works great. It will not work for any apps, only those that you have installed on your device and are not already updated to the last version.

Comment: @Gurpartap: Make sure you replace [APPID] with the actual app id for your app.

Comment: Correct app ID was put in place. (just following up) Might as well try what fichek said.

Comment: Nothing worked. Tried on iOS 5 only. Now taking users to app description page for updating.

Answer (score 0):

Just link to your app in the app store, that link will never change.

The page will show the updates right above the screenshots.

**Your best bet is to strip the update information from your apps page using JSON, or some XML parser.**

**As for the list of all updates, again, Apple compares versions of the installed apps and lists them accordingly, stripping out only the update information.**

Comment: That doesn't really accomplish what I want. For example, I currently have an app on my phone that has an update ready to download (shows up on my updates page in the app store). If I navigate in the app store to that apps main page, I see NOTHING on the page that has anything to do with an update. Even though I have that app on my phone, and it has an update waiting, I still see exactly what any user would see if they don't have the app at all. There's nothing listed above the screenshots, as you say.

Comment: They can probably achieve the same thing by just redownloading from the main page, but that's a confusing user experience. I'd prefer them to actually see the update, and be able to read the update notes if they like.

Comment: I figured out how to do it. Posted the update in the original post.

Answer (score -1):

The phobos link did not work for me so I used the following link and it works great:

```
itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftwareUpdate?id=[APPID]&mt=8
```