# iPhone App Link To App Update in AppStore

Tags: iphone, hyperlink, notifications, push

Does anyone know if you can send a user to an app's update in the appstore?

We want to do this from within the app and/or when getting a Push Notification.

Thanks!

Comment: I got it. Here's the link if anyone else needs it... http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftwareUpdate?id=[YOUR_APPID_HERE] This post gets the true credit: how do you link directly to app store app update page? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904207/how-do-you-link-directly-to-app-store-app-update-page

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible as long as you have the URL that links to your app.

I'm not 100% sure, but I seem to remember seeing something in the apple rules that means you may not be able to send a push notification advertising new apps. But an update may be ok.

Remember as well that a user may have already updated the app because they had the badge on the AppStore icon and then you push a notification out to all users. Could be annoying.